# WordPress shortcode is not generating output as expected

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Here is my shortcode

```
function feature_shortcode( $atts, $content ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'main_content' => !empty($content) ? $content : "Add a feature.",
        'width' => '',
        'screen' => array( 
                            'large' => 'col-lg',
                            'medium' => 'col-md',
                            'small' => 'col-sm',
                            'smaller' => 'col-xs',),
        'class' => ' feature',
        'icon' => '',
        'link' => '',
        'title' => ''


    ), $atts );

    extract($atts);


    return '<div class="'. $screen.$width.$class .'">
            <span class="round"><i class="fa fa-'. $icon .'"></i></span>
            <h4>'. $title .'</h4>
            <p>'. $main_content .'
            <a href="'. $link .'">
            learn more <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right">
            </i></a></p></div>';

}
add_shortcode( 'feature', 'feature_shortcode' );
```

Here is the shortcode in action

```
[feature screen="medium" width="3" icon="moon-o" title="Creative" link="https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API"]Lorem ipsum eu suspendisse, sem curabitur elit malesuada.
[/feature]
```

It returns

```
<div class="medium3 feature"> else is working fine.....</div>
```

But I want to return "col-md-" while using 'medium' as screen key. That should generate

```
<div class="col-md-3 feature"> else is working fine.....</div>
```

what should I do if I want to  return

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 feature"> else is working fine.....</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, decide how you want your user to list multiple screen and width values.

For example you may want them to be listed sequentially, separated by spaces, and matching pairs of screen and width values in order of appearance, or fallback to some default width.

```
[shortcode screen="long small medium" width="2 4"]
```

could generate:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-md-3 feature">
```

where the default `width` is `3`.

Next, as per Harsh Pandya's suggestion, create an array that maps all screen values to the respective Bootstrap classes.

```
$screens_map = array(
    'large' => 'col-lg-',
    'medium' => 'col-md-',
    'small' => 'col-sm-',
    'smaller' => 'col-xs-',
);
```

Then in your `feature_shortcode` function, use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to extract the individual user-supplied values from the screen and width attributes and store them in arrays.

```
$user_screens = explode(' ', $screen);
$user_widths = explode(' ', $width);
```

`$user_screens` and `$user_widths` will look like

```
array(
   0 => 'long',
   1 => 'small',
   2 => 'medium'
);
```

and

```
array(
   0 => '2',
   1 => '4'
);
```

Next, [iterate](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) through the user-supplied `screen` values. For each value, append a matching class to your final output. Also, if there is a matching `width` value - append it; otherwise, fallback to some default width.

```
$default_width = '3';
$bootstrap_class = '';

foreach( $user_screens as $i => $screen_value ) :
    // match the user screen value to the bootstrap class, and append it
    $bootstrap_class .= $screens_map[ $screen_value ];
    if ( $i < count($user_widths) ) :       // if there is a matching width
        $bootstrap_class .= $user_widths[$i];     // append it to the class
    else :                                  // otherwise,
        $bootstrap_class .= $default_width;     // fallback to the default width
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Finally, return the $boostrap_class in your output:

```
return '<div class="'. $bootstrap_class.$class .'">';
```

Here is the complete solution:

```
function feature_shortcode( $atts, $content ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'main_content' => !empty($content) ? $content : "Add a feature.",
        'width' => '',
        'screen' => 'medium'
        'class' => ' feature',
        'icon' => '',
        'link' => '',
        'title' => ''
    ), $atts );

    extract($atts);

    // let's map the user-supplied screen values to bootstrap classes
    $screens_map = array(
        'large' => 'col-lg-',
        'medium' => 'col-md-',
        'small' => 'col-sm-',
        'smaller' => 'col-xs-'
    );

    // extract the individual screen and width values, and place them in arrays
    $user_screens = explode(' ', $screen);
    $user_widths = explode(' ', $width);

    // default width and bootstrap class value
    $default_width = '3';
    $bootstrap_class = '';

    // iterate over the user screens, attaching the respective bootstrap class
    foreach( $user_screens as $i => $screen_value ) :

        $bootstrap_class .= $screens_map[ $screen_value ];

        if ( $i < count($user_widths) ) :
            $bootstrap_class .= $user_widths[$i];
        else :
            $bootstrap_class .= $default_width;
        endif;
    endforeach;

    return '<div class="'. $bootstrap_class.$class .'">
            <span class="round"><i class="fa fa-'. $icon .'"></i></span>
            <h4>'. $title .'</h4>
            <p>'. $main_content .'
            <a href="'. $link .'">
            learn more <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right">
            </i></a></p></div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'feature', 'feature_shortcode' );
```

Comment: It is not generting. What does that $cPrefix variable for? Where should I declear it? 
What if I want to generate different sizes. i.e. col-md-3 col-lg-6

Comment: @rushdi, I just updated the answer, see if it makes things more clear.

Comment: It definitely does. Sorry for the late replay. Thank you very much for explaining the whole thing. Thank you. It is a great help.

Comment: would you plz explain how this part works 

 if ( $i < count($user_widths) ) :
            $bootstrap_class .= $user_widths[$i].' ';
        else :
            $bootstrap_class .= $default_width.' ';
        endif;

Comment: @rushdi I'm happy to help! Please accept my answer if it helped you resolve the problem. The conditional is there in case there are more screen attributes than widths, which leaves the extra screens without a user-specified width, so we use the default width. For example when `screen="large medium small" width="6"`, the foreach loop will loop over 3 screens, but there's only 1 width. We check if the current screen's index is less than the width count, and if so we use the user_width at that index. Otherwise, we don't have a width to use, so we use the default width.

Comment: Now it's crystal clear. Thank you is not enough, but Thank you very much. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

If you are giving values to screen parameter then it will replace the default array with that value so make changes in your code like this.

```
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'main_content' => !empty($content) ? $content : "Add a feature.",
        'width' => '',
        'screen' => 'col-md-',
        'class' => ' feature',
        'icon' => '',
        'link' => '',
        'title' => ''


), $atts );

extract($atts);
$all_screens =  array(
                'large' => 'col-lg-',
                'medium' => 'col-md-',
                'small' => 'col-sm-',
                'smaller' => 'col-xs-');

if (array_key_exists($screen, $all_screens)) {
    $screen = $all_screens[$screen];
}
return '<div class="'. $screen.$width.$class .'">
        <span class="round"><i class="fa fa-'. $icon .'"></i></span>
        <h4>'. $title .'</h4>
        <p>'. $main_content .'
        <a href="'. $link .'">
        learn more <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right">
        </i></a></p></div>';
```